# A function $f: \mathbb{N} \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable iff each section $f_n$ is $\mathcal{Y}$-measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P}\mathbb{N}, \mu)$ be the measure space on the natural numbers with $\mu$ as the counting measure.  Let $(Y, \mathcal{Y}, \nu)$ be an arbitrary measure space.

I want to show that $f: \mathbb{N} \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable iff each section $f_n$ is $\mathcal{Y}$-measurable.
In this context, a section $f_n: Y \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined via $$f_n(y) = f(n,y), \quad y \in Y$$
where $f: \mathbb{N} \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$.

**Thoughts:**

Given that $f$ is a measurable function, there's a theorem that allows me to conclude that every section of $f$ is measurable so the forward direction is done.  For the backward direction, assuming each $f_n$ is $\mathcal{Y}$-measurable I have that
$$f_n^{-1}(\alpha, \infty] \in \mathcal{Y}$$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and want to show this yields for 
$$f^{-1}(\alpha, \infty] \in \mathcal{P}\mathbb{N} \times \mathcal{Y}.$$

I know that I can write $f^{-1}(\alpha, \infty] = \{(n,y): f(n,y) > \alpha\}.$

Any ideas on how to prove this direction?  General tips/strategies would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $f^{-1}((\alpha,\infty])=\bigcup_n \left(\{n\}\times f_n^{-1}((\alpha,\infty])\right)$

Comment: Not an official hw problem, though it is taken from Bartle's Elements of integration..

Comment: @PinkElephants Could you elaborate on this fabulous hint?  It was something I thought would be true, but I'm just not seeing it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S\subset Y$ is measureable, then $\{n\}\times S\subset \mathbb{N}\times Y$ is measurable for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (it is a product of the measurable sets $\{n\}\subset \mathbb{N}$ and $S\subset Y$).  Therefore
$$
f^{-1}((\alpha,\infty])=\bigcup_n \{n\}\times f_n^{-1}((\alpha,\infty])
$$
is a countable union of measurable sets, so is measurable.

Comment: I still don't see why $f^{-1}((\alpha,\infty])=\bigcup_n \{n\}\times f_n^{-1}((\alpha,\infty])$ is true.  Is there a way to achieve it starting from $f^{-1}((\alpha,\infty])=\{(n,y): f_n(y) > \alpha\}$ ?

Comment: Take the set $A:=\{(n,y):n\in\mathbb{N},f_n(y)>y\}$, and decompose it as a union $A=\bigcup_k A_k$ of subsets $A_k\subset A$, where $A_k=\{(n,y)\in A:n=k\}$. Do you see why $A_k=\{k\}\times f_k^{-1}((\alpha,\infty])$?

Comment: I do!  Very clever. Thanks so much for your help.